# Kendo UI line chart with missing values

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

How can I change the kendo ui graph configuration so that it draws line for each integer with considering "interpolate" for missing values. In the example, I wanted a line chart for all integers from 1 to 12 even though required data is not available in the data source.

Please note that, my datasource is dynamic and it can have around 1000 records.

```js
 dataSource = [{"measurementPoint":1,"data_1":10},{"measurementPoint":2,"data_1":22},{"measurementPoint":5.5,"data_1":5},
  {"measurementPoint":7,"data_1":10},{"measurementPoint":10.06,"data_1":22},{"measurementPoint":12.2,"data_1":5}];
 
 $("#chart").kendoChart({
   dataSource: { data: dataSource },
   seriesDefaults: {
  type: "line",
        markers: { visible: false }},
   categoryAxis: [{   
  justified: true,
  field: "measurementPoint",
  labels: {
   step:2,
   format: "###",
   visible:true },
  majorGridLines: { visible: false },
        majorTicks: { visible: false },
        crosshair: { visible: false }
   }],
   series: [
  { field: "data_1", name: "Pressure" }
   ],
   tooltip: {
   visible: true,
  shared: true
   }
 });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Kendo Chart</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Scatter line](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scatter-charts/scatter-line) chart instead of 'line' chart. 'Scatter line' chart properly scale chart with numeric x axis.